# Problem working with the link that has been saved but can't access and add to the dataframe

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm working on a small web scraping project of scraping data on used cars from a website. I saved the link of the pages from where the info has to be accessed in `links` variable. I check the links and it was all there

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

c_category = "cars 24"

for x in links:
    driver.get(x)
    c_id = x.strip('https://')

c_car = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"body > div.js-content > div.container > div > div._3Av8y > h1"))).text

c_brand="maruti"

c_model="baleno"

c_price=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"body > div.js-content > div.container > div > div._3Av8y > h2 > strong"))).text

c_city=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"body > div.js-content > div.container > div > div._3Av8y > div > div > div > div.col-5.col-md-3.col-xl-3._17xzA > p"))).text

c_fuel=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#overview-container > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(4) > p "))).text

c_year=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#overview-container > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2) > p "))).text

df.loc[len(df)] = [c_id, c_car,c_brand, c_model,c_price,c_city,c_fuel,c_year,c_category]
```

I should have 20 rows, but only 1 row is saved in the data frame.

Comment: Please properly format your question as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: It's probably a timing issue. You are scraping the page the second the browser says that it's done loading the page but there are background processes still running to pull the data and dump it into the page. Find something in the final loaded HTML like a table and wait for the table, etc. to exist or have X number of rows or something like that before scraping. There's not much else we can do without a link to the page.